# Is it possible to manually build Flash Builder using plain Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, flash, apache-flex, eclipse-plugin, flash-builder

As in the question. Is there a way to achieve the functionality of Flash Builder starting from plain Eclipse via installing appropriate plugins & stuff?

I'm trying to use cutting edge Eclipse version for Adobe Air development.

Comment: flash builder can be installed as an eclispe plugin , or as a separate install. flash builders comes with a lot of other things than just the AIR or FLEX sdk , so no gui builder,no ASunit integration , no code completion , no project management ,  etc ... better use flashdevelopp if you are on windows.

Comment: You should be able to trigger an ANT Script from Flash Builder to do the build.  You could also use FDT, which is an alternate to Flash Builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FDT Plugin with Eclipse. http://fdt.powerflasher.com/